# Best suited doc-tests for the verification of the correctness of a function

Tags: python, testing, doctest

**I was wondering if there is a way to determine the necessary doc-tests for a function? Perhaps a protocol that we need to follow to come up with them?** 
 The doc-tests that I could come up with are as follows:

```
>>> speed_ticket_value(0)
0

>>> speed_ticket_value(30)
100

>>> speed_ticket_value(50)
1000

>>> speed_ticket_value(-20)
0
```

However, I'm not entirely sure if the first test case covers the same functionality testing as the last one and the second as the third? Are doc-test necessarily meant to capture potential bugs in a function, or can just be used to capture the desired functionality of the developer? Sorry if my question seems silly.

> Here's the question:

[image]

**Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: all 4 of those are valid ... what happens if i do `speeding_cost("Hello")`

Comment: I'm not sure if that is allowed since the function specifies above that the parameter should be an integer. So, when you use a string, the compiler will highlight the input.

Comment: not if its `speeding_cost(a_cost)` where a_cost is user input ... of coarse if you are expecting this to be a library that is only called from within an IDE that provides type checking (there is no compiler for python ... its the IDE or a linter that can do some level of unenforced typechecking for you), then you are right maybe you dont need to handle erroneous input